# Can you share mutexes using a common struct between pthreads in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, locking, mutex

I've been working on a multithreading exercise in C using POSIX threads that implements a thread pool design. My strategy was to embed the required and shared concurrency primitives in a struct instance then pass it to every pthread.

I think my approach is flawed. It would appear `do_work()` is not dishing out jobs optimally and my book doesn't really explain a method for debugging these types of problems.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "list.h"
#include "cserver.h"

#define MAX_THREADS 5

struct thread_argvs {
    struct list *jobs_to_do;
    pthread_mutex_t job_lock;
    pthread_cond_t job_signal;
    int active;
}

struct job {
    int data; // arbitrary for example.
}

void * do_work(void *argv_values);

main(){
    
    // Stores jobs collected from client.
    struct job_list;
    list_init(&job_list);
    
    struct thread_argvs argvs;
    argvs.jobs_to_do = &job_list;
    argvs.job_lock = (pthread_mutex_t) PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    argvs.job_signal = (pthread_cond_t) PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    argvs.active = 1;
    
    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREADS];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++){
         pthread_create(&thread_list[i], NULL, do_work, (void *) argvs);
    }
    
    /* connect to a client in-between here */
        
    for (;;){
        
        struct job *new_job = malloc(sizeof(struct job));
        new_job = get_job_from_client();  
        list_push(&job_list, &new_job);
        pthread_cond_signal(&argv.job_signal);
        
        if (new_job.data == -1){ // final job
            argv.active = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_cond_signal(&argv.job_signal);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void * do_work(void *argv_values){

    struct thread_argvs *argvs = (struct thread_argvs *) argv_values;
    struct job *next_job;
    
    while(argvs.active == 1){
    
        next_job = NULL;
        
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(argvs->job_lock));
        pthread_cond_wait(&(argvs->job_signal), &(argvs->job_lock));
        
        if (list_size(argvs->jobs_to_do) > 0) {
            next_job = list_pop(&jobs_to_do);
        }
        
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(argvs->job_lock));

        if (new_job != NULL) {
            do_something_with_job(next_job->data);
            free(next_job);
            next_job = NULL;
        }
    }
    
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You must *never* call `pthread_cond_wait` without first checking to make sure that the thing you are waiting for hasn't already happened.

Comment: I'm also quite puzzled why you call `pthread_cond_signal` in a loop. What are you expecting that code to do?

Comment: The underlying idea is that main is the server. A job is synonymous to a client connecting. `get_job_from_cleint` is essentially doing `accept(socket_fd, NULL, NULL);` and blocking until it connects. After connecting, it lets the threads know that there is something new in the list.

Comment: There wouldn't be much point to mutexes if you couldn't share them between threads. Strange question.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is "Yes". And although I might do things differently, the code appears to be properly initializing and sharing `job_lock` and `job_signal`.

Answer (score 0):

You code can easily deadlock. All the calls to `pthread_cond_signal` can occur while no thread is blocked on the condition variable. Then the first thread to call `pthread_cond_wait` can just block forever.

You must *never* call `pthread_cond_wait` without first confirming (while holding the mutex!) that the thing you are going to wait for hasn't already happened.

Comment: 'Blocking forever' is not the same thing as 'deadlock'. A deadlock requires a cycle of two or more shared resources and two or more threads (or processes) each of which is waiting for a resource locked by the next while holding a resource of its own.

Comment: @user207421 See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) for the correct definition of "deadlock" -- "deadlock is any situation in which no member of some group of entities can proceed because each waits for another member, including itself, to take action, such as sending a message or, more commonly, releasing a lock". Thread A is waiting for thread B to signal the condition variable while thread B is waiting for thread A to terminate. That is a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

From the top:

```
    while(argvs.active == 1){
```

Every bit of storage that is shared between threads must have a synchronization guarantee.   Where is the guarnatee for the line quoted above?
Next up; Condition variables have no memory.   There is no doubt, if somebody sees something like:

```
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(argvs->job_lock));
        pthread_cond_wait(&(argvs->job_signal), &(argvs->job_lock));
```

That they missed the message about how condition variables work.   It is in the name `condition variables`, which means the before waiting upon them, there is some `condition` that you must check upon, and failing that condition being true, choose to `wait` upon it.

Next:  a supplicant of the last - when you `awake` on a condition variable, you need to check that the condition is satisfied before continuing.   An example follows:

```
    Lock(&VeryImportantThing);
    while (SomethingVeryImportant is not Set) {
        CondWait(&VeryImportantCond, &VeryImportantLock);
    }
    SomethingVeryImportant = Vanilla;
```